# Record video with CMOS camera using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, sd-card

Is it possible to use [this](https://www.techshopbd.com/product-categories/sensors-9925/875/640x480-cmos-camera-techshop-bangladesh) with Arduino to record and store videos on memory card?

Additionally, if someone has already done it, a tutorial link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Arduinos have two major drawbacks:

1. Not enough memory.
2. Way too slow.

There's a shield to help you do that:

http://nootropicdesign.com/ve/
http://blog.arduino.cc/2011/03/24/arduino-computer-vision-with-video-experimenter-shield/

Comment: Some more info from electronics.stackexchange: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50576/how-to-stream-arduino-based-camera-to-http-server